# PHP/CSS - add css on every td with a value > 0

Tags: php, css, syntax

I would like to add a background-color : red on every td with a value > 0 in the function mail with php.

Im trying to add an id if the val of the td is > 0 and then add css on the id with background-color.

What am i trying to do :

```
  <tbody>";
        foreach ($suiviprodmois as $arr){
        $message .="<tr>";
           foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
            $message .="<td id=' ";
            if($val > 0)
                { 
                echo "color"; 
                }
            $message .="'>".$arr[$key]."</td>";    
         }
         $message .="</tr>";
      }
      $message .="</tbody>
```

It return me :

```
colorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolorcolor if($arr > 0){ echo color }
```

Comment: `echo` should be replaced with `$message .=`

Comment: I think you should add "color" to your $message var and then `echo $message;`.

Comment: don't use id, use class. this won't resolve your issue but prevents invalid html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class instead of id.
id must be unique in the DOM.

```
foreach ($suiviprodmois as $arr) {
    $message .="<tr>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $message .= "<td" . ($val > 0 ? " class=color" : "") . ">" . $arr[$key] . "</td>";    
    }
    $message .="</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Class name should be preferably quoted.

Comment: in html5 is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code instead. I am using the dummy array please use the one you are using for this.

```
<?php
$suiviprodmois = array('abc'=>array('0','1'));
$message = '<table>';
 foreach ($suiviprodmois as $arr){
        $message .="<tr>";
           foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
           $applyid = "";
           if($val > 0)
            { 
              $applyid ='class="color"'; 
            }
            if($applyid!="")
            {
                $message .="<td ".$applyid.">";
            }
            else
            {
                $message .="<td>";
            }

            $message .= $arr[$key]."</td>";    
         }
         $message .="</tr>";
      }
      $message .="</tbody>";
      $message .= '</table>';
      echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: Why should they use this code? It is wrong, it has mistakes.

Comment: Dharman I have tested the same on my local system and working fine. May be the way i am using is different

Comment: Just because it works does not mean it is correct. ID must be unique. Besides you have not explained what your answer improved.

Comment: I just coded according to the code of the questioner. So that he can understand properly.

Comment: The problem is that you have not fixed the main issue. You have added more code, and asked the original poster to blindly copy your code and use it. If you would like to teach them, explain what you have done